# How can I set focus to datepicker or input field after the datepicker.close() call in angular

Tags: angular

I have an angular page. In a `mat-form-field`, I've created a `datepicker` the gets the year and month only so I made a **onMonthSelect** function.

**picker.component.html**

```
    <input
       matInput
       [matdatePicker]="picker"
     >
    <mat-datepicker #picker (monthSelected)="onMonthSelect($envent, picker)">
    </mat-datepicker>*
```

**picker.component.ts**

```
    onMonthSelect(date: Moment, datepicker){<br>
       datepicker.close();*

            Here I want to put the focus back to matInput

    }
```

After calling the `datepicker.close()`, the focus or cursor goes somewhere on top of the page instead on the next input field. When I press tab after the `datepicker` closes, it focus at top not the next `<div>` or component. I want to force the focus to go back to `matInput` or `matPicker`. I tried `tabindex`, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's got `closed` as Output for you.

You can get close event by return to any functions like this

```
<mat-datepicker #picker (closed)="closeEvent($event)"></mat-datepicker>
```

or simply set focus to other element instead

```
<mat-datepicker #picker2 (closed)="fieldB.focus()"></mat-datepicker>
```

Example:  [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-datepicker-work-ctvmct?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.html)

Reference: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api

Comment: The 2nd option is working for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ts:

```
datePickerFocus(){
  setTimeout(() => { 
  document.getElementById('picker2')?.focus(); ]
  }, 100);
}
```

html:

```
<mat-datepicker #picker2 (closed)="datePickerFocus()"></mat-datepicker>
```